# Google Colab [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/content/positive_images/.ipynb_checkpoints'

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, svm, histogram-of-oriented-gradients

Please help me to solve this error. I need to take the images one by one into a loop to convert in gray and calculate the HOG feactures. But betore i need take the images one by one.

````
# define path to images:

pos_im_path = r"/content/positive_images" # This is the path of our positive input dataset
# define the same for negatives
neg_im_path= r"negative_images"

# read the image files:
pos_im_listing = os.listdir(pos_im_path) # it will read all the files in the positive image path (so all the required images)
neg_im_listing = os.listdir(neg_im_path)
num_pos_samples = size(pos_im_listing) # simply states the total no. of images
num_neg_samples = size(neg_im_listing)
print(num_pos_samples) # prints the number value of the no.of samples in positive dataset
print(num_neg_samples)
data= []
labels = []

# compute HOG features and label them:
#/content/positive_images/22.png
for file in pos_im_listing: #this loop enables reading the files in the pos_im_listing variable one by one
    img = Image.open(pos_im_path + '\\' + file) # open the file
    #img = img.resize((64,128))
    gray = img.convert('L') # convert the image into single channel i.e. RGB to grayscale
    # calculate HOG for positive features
    fd = hog(gray, orientations, pixels_per_cell, cells_per_block, block_norm='L2', feature_vector=True)# fd= feature descriptor
    data.append(fd)
    labels.append(1)
    
# Same for the negative images
for file in neg_im_listing:
    img= Image.open(neg_im_path + '/' + file)
    #img = img.resize((64,128))
    gray= img.convert('L')
    # Now we calculate the HOG for negative features
    fd = hog(gray, orientations, pixels_per_cell, cells_per_block, block_norm='L2', feature_vector=True) 
    data.append(fd)
    labels.append(0)
# encode the labels, converting them from strings to integers
le = LabelEncoder()
labels = le.fit_transform(labels)```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

.ipynb_checkpoints are created by jupyter/colab notebook in your directory. The error might happen at the below two locations in your code where you pull the images from the directory.

```
for file in pos_im_listing: #this loop enables reading the files in the pos_im_listing variable one by one
    img = Image.open(pos_im_path + '\\' + file) # open the file

for file in neg_im_listing:
    img= Image.open(neg_im_path + '/' + file)
```

Add this line "if '.ipynb' not in file:" as shown below:

```
for file in pos_im_listing:
    if '.ipynb' not in file:
        img = Image.open(pos_im_path + '\\' + file) # open the file
    
for file in neg_im_listing:
    if '.ipynb' not in file:
        img= Image.open(neg_im_path + '/' + file)
```

This should safely ignore the notebook checkpoints and import the images. Or if all your images have a certain extension, you could specify like "if '.jpeg' in file" as below:

```
    for file in pos_im_listing:
        if '.jpeg' in file:
            img = Image.open(pos_im_path + '\\' + file) 
        
    for file in neg_im_listing:
        if '.jpeg' in file:
            img= Image.open(neg_im_path + '/' + file)
```

you can also create a separate directory exclusively for images.